# Excessive view updates unless HorizontalScrollView wrapped with another View

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

So, I have an activity that contains a `HorizontalScrollView`.  Here is a cleaned up xml.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    style="@style/style_DrawerLayout">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_std"/>
    <include
        layout="@layout/btn_bar_scroll"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/navigation_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And my `btn_bar_scroll` (only three button shown for clarity)

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation"horizontal">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="BTN1"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic1"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="BTN2"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic2"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="BTN3"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic3"/>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

It works fine, exactly as expected.  Except that when using `Show GPU View Updates`, I've noticed that every view on the entire page updates whenever the scroll is dragged either way (even the `Toolbar` updates).  Not so great for performance.

Weirdly, by wrapping the `HorizontalScrollView` with another view, like with this `FrameLayout`, the unnecessary view updates stop (only the `HorizontalScrollView` updates when it is flicked). Any advice?  I'd rather not have the extra `FrameLayout` for seemingly no reason.

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="BTN1"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic1"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="BTN2"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic2"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="BTN3"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic3"/>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```